# How do I generate SMILES using machine learning in Mathematica

Tags: machine-learning, curated-data, chemistry

I am wondering if anyone has experience with generating molecules using machine learning in Mathematica. There are a bunch of papers these days with such applications/developments. For example, https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c01496. Another example on Medium is https://medium.com/@sunitachoudhary103/generating-molecules-using-a-char-rnn-in-pytorch-16885fd9394b

I know about Molecule and associated chemistry functions. I am interested in how SMILES strings could be generated, perhaps, by adapting some neural networks that work for such kinds of applications.

If someone's aware of examples/tutorials that cover this, it would be great, if you could share.

Cheers!

Comment: A challenge with SMILES is guaranteeing semantic structure. Arguably, methods for representing molecular graphs like SELFIES https://github.com/aspuru-guzik-group/selfies might be easier to implement, as ANY generated string is valid.  (These can always be translated into a corresponding SMILES) It should be straightforward to implement SELFIES using MMA term replacement (or just import the python library).  Back when the paper was first posted, to understand it better I sketched out a rough demo from the appendix https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jschrier0/Published/2019.10.05_selfies_demo.nb

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think you could post this as an answer?

Comment: There is this example, [Generating Molecules With SELFIES](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/Selfies/tutorial/GeneratingMoleculesWithSELFIES.html).  It doesn't use machine learning explicitly, but rather shows the raw tools you would use in a ML application.

Answer (score 0):

A great paper that covers this topic can be found here:

[Machine Learning Methods in Chemistry](https://jamesbonnar.org.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/)

The Author uses a Markovian text generator to generate SMILES strings that are variations on a theme. The invalid SMILES are culled with a Mathematica function. The code requires Mathematica 10 or later.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/116551)